# Is it possible to combine these methods? (Java Generics)

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm working on a homework assignment for University which does not allow me to change the properties of the classes. I came up with the following code for a search method, but I can't help but notice the duplicate code. I am required to build two search methods. One that searches an `ArrayList<Person>` and one that searches an `ArrayList<Module`. Both `Person` and `Module` have a `String name` property.

```
public static <T extends Person> ArrayList<T> findPerson(List<T> list, String query) {
    ArrayList<T> matching = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (s.name.contains(query)) matching.add(s);
    });
    return matching;
}

public static <T extends Module> ArrayList<T> findModule(List<T> list, String query) {
    ArrayList<T> matching = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (s.name.contains(query)) matching.add(s);
    });
    return matching;
}
```

Is it possible to combine these methods without changing the class structure? I tried something along these lines but it still doesn't seem to work: (different type argument in method signature)

```
public static <T extends Person, Module> ArrayList<T> findModule(List<T> list, String query) {
    ArrayList<T> matching = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (s.name.contains(query)) matching.add(s);
    });
    return matching;
}
```

Edit: Here are the classes:

```
public abstract class Person extends TableItem {

public String name, famName, street, zip, city;
public String[] data = new String[7];

...
}

public class Module extends TableItem {

private Manager manager;
public String[] data = new String[5];
public String name, nr, profID, semester, part;
public ArrayList<String> participants;

...
}

public abstract class TableItem {

public abstract String getString();
public abstract void updateData();
}
```

Comment: Do `Person ` and `Module` implement the same interface, or extend the same base class?

Comment: No, they don't. edit. oops, they do, but its not the field i need to search

Comment: Can you put the classes in your question? And is it a problem if you decide to make them implement a common interface?

Comment: Are there getter methods for the name (and other fields)?

Comment: @rgettman Yes, I realize now that there is indeed a common getter `getString()` which is a concatenation of several of the string fields in the class. One of these components is `name` so the `String.contains` method will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you make both your classes implement the same interface, like `NamedItem` which would have a function `getName()`, it would be much simpler, because you make your function take `List<? extends NamedItem>`. If this is not possible, you will have to provide a `Function` to determine what `String` property to match.

```
public static <T> List<T> find(List<T> list, String query, Function<T, String> keyExtractor) {
    return list
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> keyExtractor.apply(s).contains(query))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
List<Person> matchingPersons = find(allPersons, query1, Person::getName);
List<Module> matchingModules = find(allModules, query1, Module::getName);
```

You can use it with any property, not just name. You just pass the function that extracts the `String` you want to match as the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to specify more than one base type for a generic type is with the `&` syntax:

```
<T extends Person & Module>
```

But in that case `T` must extend both at the same time, so it is not what you're looking for.

To combine your two methods, the types must share a common interface, e.g.

```
public interface Named {
    String getName();
}
```

Now, if both `Person` and `Module` extends/implements the `Named` interface, your method can be:

```
public static <T extends Named> ArrayList<T> findNamed(List<T> list, String query) {
    return list.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().contains(query))
               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```